# Google Tag Manager blocked in some clients and by adblockers

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a problem in my website and i need your help!
I implemented google tag manager in my website, i added the script gtm and have a problem in some of clients like firefox or some adBlockers like uBlock are blocking GTM.
How can i avoid this to never block gtm to users of my website?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to block users who block gtm? or that you want to force gtm to run even if a user is using an adblocker?

Comment: I want to force gtm running for users @MattBunch

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid this as this is a choice done by the users themselves.

Comment: It's not possible to force gtm running without any changes from users?

Comment: Most blockers blocks requests to all the google servers, so if you want to bypass them, you would need to create a proxy to load in the GTM/GA scripts. It would probably be easier for you to look for a self-hosted analytics solution instead.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it is useless to integrate google tag manager in my solution, I must add my scripts in my code

Comment: You’re only having issues with people who are choosing to block it. You will still be collecting good data from people who aren’t.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of solutions, you can set the tag that read if user use `ADBlocker` or `incognito window`, and if you want to bypass them, you can but the solution is Kind of greyhat scaled because you have to use fingerprint solution so it is on you.